# Comparison Operator in Powershell

Tags: powershell, comparison

I have a script that is currently working.  There are two groups that need to be omitted from the CSV that is exported.  As it currently sits it works. see below:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\importactiveusers.csv | ForEach-Object{

$user = get-aduser -Identity $_.samaccountname -Properties name, samaccountname, memberof

$(
if ($user.memberof.count -gt 1) {
    foreach ($group in $user.MemberOf -notlike "*groupname*") {
        $user | select name, samaccountname,@{n='User Group';e={($_.memberof -like “*Certifiers-*” - 
        replace '^CN=(?<Name>.*?),(?:OU|CN).*$', '${Name}' -join ', ')}}, @{n='group';e={$group - 
        replace '^CN=(?<Name>.*?),(?:OU|CN).*$', '${Name}' -join ', '}}, @{n='Group Description';e= 
        {(Get-ADGroup $group -Properties description).description}},@{n='Date of File';e={(Get-date - 
       format M/d/yyy)}}
       }}
       )
       }| Export-Csv -path 'C:\Users\adiaz\ADUserAccessList.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

in  the foreach line I have -notlike "*groupname*" i need to ad another group name to his that gets omitted.  But when I do it does not return any results.  What would be teh best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

replaced -notlike with -notmatch